# Sodium benzoate in soft drinks reacting to produce benzene?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

Regarding chemical synergies, I read: if someone ingests various products containing sodium benzoate (for example soft drinks that exist) AND if one has had some quantity of vitamin C there might be 'reactions' that produce benzene, a carcinogen.

Some people have told me you'd have to drink a lot of pop for this to happen (assuming you have had some vitamin C during the day), but how much pop is a lot?

Given one has had a glass of orange juice say, how much pop would one have to drink before a benzene molecule is formed?

Comment: I've never heard of this before. Can you support your statement with a claim? This sounds like it should be on Skeptics.

Comment: Can sodium benzoate and vitamin C  interact 'badly'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reaction taking place is described in article [Benzene production from decarboxylation of benzoic acid in the presence of ascorbic acid and a transition-metal catalyst](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jf00029a001) and its importance for food safety recently reviewed in [Evaluation of Accelerated UV and Thermal Testing for Benzene Formation in Beverages Containing Benzoate and Ascorbic Acid](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1750-3841.2010.01536.x/full).

To summarize, the reaction CAN occur, namely at elevated temperatures (>50 °C) and UV-light and in presence of transition metal. Even if the reaction takes place, the amount of benzene formed is either below detection limit, or below limit for drinking water.

For the end user it means, that in extremely unlucky situation, the benzene can form in quantity, which is not considered safe to drink in unlimited amount for the whole life (1 ppb). As such, I would consider the benzene formation as very weak argument against such beverages (mainly if compared with other problems, such as sugar content and associated obesity).

Comment: Thank you for the info. Would drinking an average of 4 L. of pop per day make benezene formation more likely?

Comment: I have troubles understanding your problem as a valid one. I am not aware of any reasonable diet containing 4L of pop per day. Recommended WATER intake is ~2L per day. If you are about to drink 4L of pop per day, be ready to die from anything else but benzene caused cancer.

Comment: I'm not saying this is part of a reasonable diet yet I have seen many young adults buy 2 L. bottles of Coke say seemingly to drink them for the caffeine and sugar buzz. I think a lot of young people and adults use Coke and Pepsi in a way similar to energy drinks. In this obsession to be energized and/or stay awake aren't you worried some may be drinking too much in one day. If a young person drinks a lot of Coke in one day for weeks to stay awake while studying ,say; it may not accumulate enough benzene  to do harm but does this molecule stay in the body for a while?

Comment: Please see the toxicology of benzene, very brief: http://www.crios.be/Benzene/toxicology.htm, very long: http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/toxprofiles/tp.asp?id=40&tid=14
The benzene is really not a problem here.

Comment: If sodium benzoate is harmless given many people drink a lot of pop during the day and ingest it in many processed food items; there may be a tiny amount of benzene formed that is within 'safe' standards. Yet how efficient is the human body at getting rid of such molecules as benzene ,even if it exists in the body in tiny amounts? Over time it may accumulate..

Comment: Actually, the toxicology of benzene is quite interesting. The problem is not the benzene itself, but benzene oxide, which is formed as the body tries to get rid of benzene. The benzene itself does not accumulate, but mutations caused by benzene oxide do. But really please, read some toxicology, nice short and accurate here: http://www.hpa.org.uk/webc/hpawebfile/hpaweb_c/1194947391801
To say, gallons of coke _may_ contain the same amount of benzene as you inhale during smoking of 1 cigarette.

Comment: So from ingesting A LOT of sodium benzoate in pop drinks and many common food products in one month ,say could the human body in trying to get rid of benzene make a fair amount of benzene oxide that causes the accumulating mutations. We as a modern society seem to use a lot of preservatives (that are only for longer 'shelf life' and save a company money). OVER a few years could these mutations accumulate to harmful levels?

Comment: Although quite understandable, your position misses important thing, at that is food security. The longer "shelf life" is a reason for no famine in developed world in last century. We are not only able to produce enough food, but also store it efficiently, so that we do not have to throw it away rotten. So if you can, buy fresh food. If not, buy preserved food. If not, death of starvation is inevitable.

Comment: I did mention I was talking about modern society not the developed world. Should ANYBODY rich or poor have to ingest preservative laden food. Maybe a company could offer a preservative- free version of all their products for a slightly bigger price. It seems most average North Americans including 'tons' of students buy processed food.  Why does Europe seem to use less preservatives than in North America?

Comment: So benzene oxide can cause mutations that accumulate. It forms as the body tries to get rid of benzene. So my question should really apply to Benzene Oxide. If we drink a lot of pop and eat processed food with sodium benzoate and potassium benzoate , over a month would this form a lot of Benzene Oxide in the Body?? ( which accumulates and causes mutations)

Comment: Can a 2 litre bottle of Coke say 3 times a week give one enough benezene oxide to cause mutations?